Label points individually in ggplot2/ggarrange graphs
I created three plots in ggplot2 to show the sex ratio in a panel dataset over different years.
Everything worked well, but when labeling the points of the graph and then putting them together with ggarrange some of the lables just drop out of the graph and cannot be read anymore or they overlap even thought I specified position = position_dodge.
I created the plots with the following code:
plot1 <- 
  ggplot(data, aes(x = Year, y = perc*100, colour = Sex)) +
  geom_path(aes(group=Sex)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("skyblue3", "darkred"))+
  labs(title = "Sex Ratio", x = "years", y = "percentage") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), panel.grid.major.x = element_blank()) +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(round(perc*100), "%")), position = position_dodge(width =1), vjust = 2, size = 2.5, colour = "black", check_overlap = TRUE)


I did this for all the three plots and then I tried to arrange them with ggarrange in the following way:
plot_together <- ggarrange(plot1, plot2, plot3, ncol = 2, nrow = 2,
                                            common.legend = TRUE, legend = "bottom")

What I get is:

I don't know how to solve the problem that some of the labels are not seen anymore.
I am only able to put all the labels together above or below, but not single ones above and other ones below or something like that.
Is one of you having an idea how to solve this?
Thank you in advance!

Welcome to SO! It would be easier to help you if you provide a minimal reproducible example including a snippet of your input data best shared using dput() or using some fake data or using a built-in dataset.

This said: One option would be to increase the bottom expansion of the y scale using e.g. something like + scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = .05, add = c(.05, 0)) which besides the default multiplicative expansion of .05 will add an additional additive .05 at the lower end. BTW: In your case position_dodge will have no effect on the placment of the labels.

Thank you @stefan!! I have increased the bottom expansion and now every label can be read. But now, due to the bigger scale, two values seem to overlap a bit. Do you know how to solve this?

aside: Since both variables always sum up to 100%, one of the two complementary lines is redundant. It could (and, according to some, should) be omitted anyway.

As stated in previous comments, there is an argument for plotting only one sex group as they mirror each other. However, there are cases where your desired outcome is useful so here's a reprex. It involves manipulating your data and adding a column containing values to vertically offset the labels based on the perc value.
To achieve this, I have used tidyr::pivot_longer() so that only one offset column e.g. "adjust" is required. Alternatively, you could create three separate adjust columns. If you choose the latter, you will need to change vjust = adjust so that each plot has the correct adjust column values.
An issue with this method is that if there is a tie for Year values e.g 0.50 in Sex Ratio 2, only one label will appear. You could manually change these adjust values if necessary.
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggpubr)

data <- data.frame(Sex = rep(c("Female", "Male"), each = 5),
                 Year = 2019:2023,
                 sr1 = c(.41, .43, .45, .45, .46, .59, .57, .55, .54, .54),
                 sr2 = c(.41, .50, .47, .48, .48, .59, .50, .53, .52, .52),
                 sr3 = c(.41, .39, .40, .42, .44, .59, .61, .59, .58, .56))

# Pivot to long format, add value to offset (vjust) labels based on max ratio value
data <- data |>
  pivot_longer(-c(Sex, Year),
               names_to = "ratio",
               values_to = "perc") |>
  arrange(ratio) |>
  mutate(adjust = if_else(perc == max(perc), -1, 2), .by = c(ratio, Year))

# Set variable to increase y-axes by, adjust to suit
pad <- 0.2

# Filter data by ratio value. The ratio column value may differ for your actual
# data, modify to suit e.g. change "sr1" etc. to match the values in ratio column
plot1 <- 
  ggplot(filter(data, ratio == "sr1"), 
         aes(x = Year, y = perc, colour = Sex)) +
  geom_path(aes(group = Sex)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("skyblue3", "darkred")) +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(round(perc * 100), "%"), vjust = adjust),
            position = position_dodge(width = 1),
            size = 2.5,
            colour = "black") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(accuracy = 1),
                     expand = expansion(mult = pad)) +
  labs(title = "Sex Ratio", x = "Year", y = "Percentage") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank())

plot2 <- 
  ggplot(filter(data, ratio == "sr2"), 
         aes(x = Year, y = perc, colour = Sex)) +
  geom_path(aes(group = Sex)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("skyblue3", "darkred")) +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(round(perc * 100), "%"), vjust = adjust),
            position = position_dodge(width = 1),
            size = 2.5,
            colour = "black") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(accuracy = 1),
                     expand = expansion(mult = pad)) +
  labs(title = "Sex Ratio 2", x = "Year", y = "Percentage") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank())

plot3 <- 
  ggplot(filter(data, ratio == "sr3"), 
         aes(x = Year, y = perc, colour = Sex)) +
  geom_path(aes(group = Sex)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("skyblue3", "darkred")) +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(round(perc * 100), "%"), vjust = adjust),
            position = position_dodge(width = 1),
            size = 2.5,
            colour = "black") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(accuracy = 1),
                     expand = expansion(mult = pad)) +
  labs(title = "Sex Ratio 3", x = "Year", y = "Percentage") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank())


plot_together <- ggarrange(plot1, plot2, plot3, ncol = 2, nrow = 2,
                           common.legend = TRUE, legend = "bottom")

plot_together


